# C# - Assembly Name String isnt rendering correct when loading Exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[Here's a GIF showing whats wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aehIw.gif)
**NOTE: It works perfectly fine with DownloadFile() it downloads under the right name and path (Even the mbox before it is correct) - But everything else after it fails to be the right name and path.**

---

Need the .exe to test?
https://github.com/ImReallyShiny/SAIO/blob/master/Test.exe
(Scan it if needed, But it is 100% safe)

---

This is absolute wizardry that's going on.

Somehow when I run my "Auto-Update" code from the "Start" Button on Visual Studio, It outputs the correct file path and file name (with .exe)...
But when I open the Built .exe, It does some wizardry resulting in it slashing everything after (& Including) the "-" but keeping the .exe somehow.

The code is EXACTLY the same on BOTH .exe's the only thing I could see as the reason, Is some issue with Webclient Getting the version more than 1 time (Yet its tied to a string var so it shouldn't matter) or some kind of Glitch with my VisualStudio setup (Cache, Propogation, PC Restart Needed or something)

---

This is a hard question to explain, So I added some Inline Commenting to explain where the issue is and what it is.

Code:

```
//Using WebClient, get the Newest File Version;
using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{

    //Latest Version; (This is the number after the - for the filename - Excluding .exe)
    string LatestVersion = wc.DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ImReallyShiny/SAIO/master/version.txt");
    //This is the Location itself e.g C:/Users/Shiny/Desktop/{appname}.exe
    string ExecutableLocation = typeof(Program).Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "");
    //The build's File Version;
    string CurrentVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(ExecutableLocation).ProductVersion;
    //Final Name String; As you can see it SHOULD output as: AppName-1.2.4.5.exe
    string CurrentExecutableName = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name + "-" + LatestVersion + ".exe";

    //If the Latest Version is Newer then the Current Version;
    if (LatestVersion != CurrentVersion)
    {

        //Download the Latest Version of the EXE file; (Gets the name and path perfectly fine)
        wc.DownloadFile("https://github.com/ImReallyShiny/SAIO/raw/master/SAIO.exe", CurrentExecutableName);

        //Show a MessageBox asking to open Explorer to the file; - This should output "{Path}/AppName-1.2.4.5.exe" but it only does when opening from VS
        DialogResult mb = MessageBox.Show("Continue usage on the new update. Open Explorer and go to the Directory containing the updated .exe located at: " + ExecutableLocation.Replace("SAIO.EXE", CurrentExecutableName + " ?\""), "New Update Downloaded!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        if (mb == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //Go to where SAIO is and select the New Update.exe; (This also fails to select the right .exe, It selects "SAIO.EXE" when it should be selecing the AppName-1.2.4.5.exe
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select,\"" + ExecutableLocation.Replace("/", "\\").Replace("SAIO.EXE", CurrentExecutableName) + "\"");
        }

    }
    else
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());

    }

}
```

Get what im saying?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply that the filename is (sometimes) `SAIO.exe` or some other case.

Seeing as `Replace` doesn't have an overload to allow you to specify `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` (or `somethingElseIgnoreCase`), the best solution is to use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) to get the full folder name you want, rather than just expecting there to be exactly one `SAIO.EXE` in the path.

E.g. your last line could be (untested):

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select,\"" +
    Path.GetDirectoryName(ExecutableLocation.Replace("/", "\\"))
    + "\\" + CurrentExecutableName + "\"");
```

`GetDirectoryName` handles `/` separators fine, but you'll still want to adjust them sometime to ensure the `explorer` call to works properly.

Really that last line should be (again untested):

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select,\"" +
    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(ExecutableLocation.Replace("/", "\\")),
        CurrentExecutableName) + "\"");
```